# How to define SSH port for target server with znapzendsetup

Tags: ssh, znapzend

I have a firewalled server to send data to over ssh on public network, but the SSH port is not the default 22. How do I configure the port to znapzendzetup?

For mbuffer setting the port is not an issue, but if the communication is unencrypted, I do not feel comfortable sending data over it.

Comment: it's not clear, to define a port in the client use the -P flag, to make the daemon listen on a non standard port edit it's config file. I don't know what the rest of your question means

Comment: The rest of my question refers to the ability to define a port when using mbuffer, but not when using ssh. I'll check on the -P flag for client, but I would just like the "zetup" to finish and successfully connect to the host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have special configuration for a particular connection, just create a Host section in your `~/.ssh/config` file and do whatever magic you see fit. Make sure you use the .ssh/config of the user you are running your `znapzend` under ...

Comment: This should solve my issue. Is there any reason not to have it as a command line parameter similar to e.g. scp?

Comment: the complexity of all possible ssh configurations is best covered by adding an appropriate entry to the .ssh/config file ... there would be no end to the options we would have to add.